# Quiero retornar una lista de un join linq pero no se como hacerlo, osea no se que va dentro del List<????>

Tags: linq, join

Ya intente crear un objeto a partir de la query del join osea de los atributos que quiero que se vea pero aun asi no puedo realizar el retorno

```
    public List<????> ListaJoin()
    {
        var resultado = (from ad in model.AlumnoDireccion
                         join a in model.Alumno on ad.AlumnoId equals a.AlumnoId
                         select new { ad.Direccion, a.Nombre, a.Apellido, a.Estado, a.PromedioAcumulado }).ToList();

        return resultado();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la expresión LINQ estás creando un [tipo anónimo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/bb397696.aspx#M%C3%A9xico%20(Espa%C3%B1ol)) (`new { ... }`), estos solo pueden ser usados dentro del método en que son declarados, es decir no puedes devolver una instancia de este facilmente. Lo más sencillo es crear una clase más con solo esas propiedades para devolver los datos que quieres.

```
public class AlumnoDireccion
{
    public string Direccion { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apellido { get; set; }
    public string Estado { get; set; }        
    public double PromedioAcumulado { get; set }
}
```

---

```
public List<AlumnoDireccion> ListaJoin()
{
    return (from ad in model.AlumnoDireccion
            join a in model.Alumno on ad.AlumnoId equals a.AlumnoId
            select new AlumnoDireccion 
            { 
                Direccion = ad.Direccion,
                Nombre = a.Nombre,
                Apellido = a.Apellido,
                Estado = a.Estado,
                PromedioAcumulado = a.PromedioAcumulado
            }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Me sirvió muchas gracias era justo lo que necesitaba

Answer (score 0):

Para el caso que expones usa `object`. En lo personal prefiero crear una clase esta aplicar `new MyClase` y esa retoronarla.introducir el código aquí

Answer (score 0):

La solución que expuso @Equiso es la.mas adecuada 
Solo que le encuentro una falla enorme 
Cuando haces joins con Linq debes asignar el join dentro de un nuevo objeto 
Ya que si por algún. Motivo el ID no se encuera en la segunda tabla, el registro de la primera no te aparecerá y ni te mandara como null
Tell comiendo cambiar un Poco el query 
                         join a in model.Alumno on ad.AlumnoId equals a.AlumnoId into alumosObj 
                        From alumnos in alumosObj.Defaulting empty()
Y  cualquier referencia que hagas a la tabla alumno ahora hazla al objeto alumnos por ejemplo
AlumnosObj.Nombre,

Comment: Esto seria un left join verdad?

Comment: Es para cualquier tipo de join, ya que es un detallito que tiene Linq