# ¿Cómo retornar una lista en una consulta, utilizando linq con Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, linq

como retornar la siguiente consulta desde un modelo utilizando entity framework(soy principiante en este framework):

```
         var datos = (from x in db.ReporteOperativo select new { x.REFERENCIA,x.DESCRIPCIONMATERIAL, x.ADUANAENTRADA,x.NOMBREBUQUE, x.IMPORTADOREXPORTADOR, x.PARQUEEOLICO, x.REGIMENOPERACION, x.HBL, x.TIPOCONTENEDOR, x.NUMEROCONTENEDOR, x.ETD, x.ETA,x.ATA,x.FACTURACOMERCIAL, x.PO, x.NCR, x.ACCODE,x.VALORMERFACTURA, x.FLETE, x.SEGUROINCREMENTAL, x.OTROSINCREMENTABLE, x.TOTALVALORFACTURA, x.TIPOCAMBIO, x.VALORADUANAMN, x.DTAMN, x.PARTESII, x.IGIMN, x.IEPS, x.IVAMN, x.MULTAS, x.RECARGOS, x.REVALIDACION, x.TOTALEFECTIVOMN, x.FECHAPAGO,x.FECHAVENCIMIENTO,x.SECCIONADUANA, x.FECHADESADUANAMIENTO, x.SELALEATORIA, x.FECHAENTREGA, x.ALMACENAJE, x.DESCONSOLIDACION, x.PARTIDASSINIVA, x.MANIOBRAS, x.FLETELOCAL, x.TOTALLOCAL, x.HONORARIOS, x.TOTALOPERACION, x.TOTALLSP, x.EXCHANGERATE, x.AMOUNTUSD, x.RESPONSABLE, x.Status.STATUSAA}).ToList();
```

solo permite realizarla pero desde el controlador, yo deseo hacer todo tipo de consultas en el modelo sin embargo se me da el problema para retornarlas como lista, es una relación oneToMany.
(Adjunto la img del erro que constantemente me sale o como podria se una consulta que se puede retornar para pintar un gridView para exportarlo a excel con una relación oneToMany)

[image: Adjunto la img del erro que constantemente me sale o como podria se una consulta que se puede retornar para pintar un gridView para exportarlo a excel con una relación oneToMany]

Comment: Guadalupe, te doy la bienvenida y te invito a realizar el [tour] para que 
conozcas el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Para realizar preguntas es 
importante revises [ask] que te brinda información para realizar una 
buena pregunta, esta sea bien recibida en la comunidad y de esta forma 
obtengas buenas respuestas!, un gran saludo y suerte!.

Comment: Parece que la otra respuesta es la solución, mira éste enlace:https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/61114/quiero-retornar-una-lista-de-un-join-linq-pero-no-se-como-hacerlo-osea-no-se-qu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu carpeta de modelos podrías agregar una clase  que contenga los atributos que requieres

```html
    public class OperativoConstruccion
    {
        public string Referencia { get; set; }
        public string DescripcionMaterial { get; set; }
        public string Responsable { get; set; }
        public string Estatus { get; set; }
    }
```

y ya en tu consulta puedes indicar que retorna `OperativoConstruccion` y no la clase que estas definiendo completa quedaría algo así la consulta :

```html
public List<OperativoConstruccion> datosExcel()
{
var datos = (from x in db.ReporteOperativo select new OperativoConstruccion {Referencia = x.REFERENCIA ,DescripcionMaterial=X.DESCRIPCIONMATERIAL,Responsable=x.RESPONSABLE , Estatus=x.Status.STATUSAA}).toList();
return datos;
}
```

o si lo que quieres es retornar todos los valores simplemente has la consulta así:

```html
public List<ReporteOperativo> datosExcel()
{
var datos =  db.ReporteOperativo.toList();
return datos;
}
```

Comment: de echo por ser una relación oneToMany de ReporteOperativo con Status: en ReporteOperativo tengo lo Sig;  [ForeignKey("Status")]
        [Display(Name = "Status")]
        public int? IdStatus { get; set; }

        public virtual Status Status { get; set; }                                                          y en Status esto:     public virtual ICollection<ReporteOperativo> ReporteOperativo { get; set; }                                                                                     y lo que deseo retornar es una lista con todos los datos de reporte operativo mas el estatus.

Comment: el error indica es que en tu método retornaras una lista de ReporteOperativo y en lugar de eso retornas una lista de un objeto anónimo, de igual manera la primera propuesta puede ayudarte a resolver el problema o podrías editar tu pregunta incluyendo lo que pusiste en el primer comentario(tus clases) @GuadalupeYañez

Comment: tengo una imagen de la prueba de la primera respuesta pero veo que en respuesta a  los comentarios no permite adjuntar imágenes.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con esto

```
List<ReporteOperativo> lstReporte = new List<ReporteOperativo>();
lstReporte  = (from x in db.ReporteOperativo select new { x.REFERENCIA,x.DESCRIPCIONMATERIAL, x.ADUANAENTRADA,x.NOMBREBUQUE, x.IMPORTADOREXPORTADOR, x.PARQUEEOLICO, x.REGIMENOPERACION, x.HBL, x.TIPOCONTENEDOR, x.NUMEROCONTENEDOR, x.ETD, x.ETA,x.ATA,x.FACTURACOMERCIAL, x.PO, x.NCR, x.ACCODE,x.VALORMERFACTURA, x.FLETE, x.SEGUROINCREMENTAL, x.OTROSINCREMENTABLE, x.TOTALVALORFACTURA, x.TIPOCAMBIO, x.VALORADUANAMN, x.DTAMN, x.PARTESII, x.IGIMN, x.IEPS, x.IVAMN, x.MULTAS, x.RECARGOS, x.REVALIDACION, x.TOTALEFECTIVOMN, x.FECHAPAGO,x.FECHAVENCIMIENTO,x.SECCIONADUANA, x.FECHADESADUANAMIENTO, x.SELALEATORIA, x.FECHAENTREGA, x.ALMACENAJE, x.DESCONSOLIDACION, x.PARTIDASSINIVA, x.MANIOBRAS, x.FLETELOCAL, x.TOTALLOCAL, x.HONORARIOS, x.TOTALOPERACION, x.TOTALLSP, x.EXCHANGERATE, x.AMOUNTUSD, x.RESPONSABLE, x.Status.STATUSAA}).ToList();
return lstReporte;
```

Comment: de echo ya lo realice de esa forma pero me sale el soguiente error, reitero es una relación oneToMany de ReporteOperativo con Status (en ReporteOperativo puse la llave foranea de Status y en la clase de Status un objeto de tipo lista de ReporteOperativo).

Comment: por ser una relación oneToMany de ReporteOperativo con Status: en ReporteOperativo tengo lo Sig;  [ForeignKey("Status")]
        [Display(Name = "Status")]
        public int? IdStatus { get; set; }

        public virtual Status Status { get; set; }                                                          y en Status esto:     public virtual ICollection<ReporteOperativo> ReporteOperativo { get; set; }                                                                                     y lo que deseo retornar es una lista con todos los datos de reporte operativo mas el estatus.

Comment: ya quedo solucionado, cree otra clase donde declare nuevamente los atributos y Status lo declare como un string, en esta clase agregue el método para retornar los datos para llenar mi GridView. y se esa forma me permitió retornar los datos anonymous.

Comment: Perfecto, creo que ayer te dieron una solución parecida, que hicieras una clase con todos los atributos, porque status según entendí yo, pertenecía a otra clase a la de los demás atributos, y no lo reconocía la lista, por ser de otro tipo de objeto. Recuerda que cuando te permita StackOverflow, marcar tu solución como respuesta ;)

Comment: De acuerdo muchas gracias, es que como de igual forma soy nueva en el blog :)